# Pandas json normalize

Tags: pandas, normalization

Can someone help on how to put this json structure into pandas dataframe ? I would like the final structure to have date, high, low, open, low, close as the column.
The issues I have with this structure is that the key is a running numbers (eg 1607956200, 1607956500, 1607956800 ...) and I can't possibly lay out all the running numbers.

I have tried with the code below but I get all the data in the column with only 1 row.

```
response=requests.get(url).text
data = json.loads(response)
df = pd.json_normalize(data['history'] )
```

Below is an example of `data`

```
data = {"meta": {"regularMarketPrice": 9.78, "chartPreviousClose": 9.02, "previousClose": 9.78, "scale": 3, "dataGranularity": "5m", "range": "" },
        "history": {"1607956200": { "date": "14-12-2020", "open": 9.13, "high": 9.18, "low": 9.12, "close": 9.14 },
                    "1607956500": { "date": "14-12-2020", "open": 9.14, "high": 9.14, "low": 9.08, "close": 9.1 },
                    "1607956800": { "date": "14-12-2020", "open": 9.1, "high": 9.11, "low": 9.09, "close": 9.1 },}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the dataframe and then transpose

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['history']).T

                  date  open  high   low close
1607956200  14-12-2020  9.13  9.18  9.12  9.14
1607956500  14-12-2020  9.14  9.14  9.08  9.10
1607956800  14-12-2020  9.10  9.11  9.09  9.10
```